# How can I create a Gatling simulation that peaks/spikes every hour and returns to normal after 10 minutes?

Tags: gatling

I am trying to create a test that runs for 10 hours with 100 users. 
Every hour, i'd like to increase the number of users by 50 for 10 minutes and than go 
back to 100 users. Note that I am talking about number of users and not TPS.

Since I couldn't find any normal way to do it with once scenario, I thought about the following approach. I create two scenarios and run them simultaneously:

```
  setUp(scenario1.inject(rampConcurrentUsers(1) to (100) during (10 minutes))
    .protocols(httpconf),
    scenario2.inject(nothingFor(60 minutes), rampUsers(50) during (10 minute)).protocols(httpconf))
    .maxDuration(10 hours))
```

The problem with this simulation is that the users that start to ramp up from scenario2 never stop, so after an hour I end up with 150 users until the end of the simulation.

Note that Scenario1 and scenario2 are identical apart from simulation name... there must be a better way to achieve this with one scenario or at least make it work with two.
Any ideas/help will be highly appreciated!

UPDATE:

As suggested by John, I tried the following code:

```
 setUp(fastZappingSpeed.inject(nothingFor(1 second),sInjection(1): _*
  ).protocols(httpconf)).maxDuration(6 minutes)

  def sInjection( hours : Int )  = {
    val seq = Seq(rampUsers(10) during (1 minute))
    var i = hours
    while ( i > 0 ) {
      seq  ++ Seq(nothingFor(2 minute)) ++ Seq(rampUsers(10) during (1 minute))
      i -= 1
    }
    seq
  }
```

However, I did not get the expected behavior:

[image]

If I wrote the exact same behavior "manually", I did get the expected result:

```
  setUp(scenario.inject(
    rampUsers(10) during (1 minute),
    nothingFor(2 minute),
    rampUsers(10) during (1 minute)
  ).protocols(httpconf)).maxDuration(3 minutes)
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Notice, you are passing sInjection(1), which means you have a sequence of exactly one bump.  If you want 2 bumps, you need to pass in 2.

Comment: Its just an example I pasted... See the post that I've added, I solved this using a different approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up solving it with a different approach.
Instead of injecting users and trying to remove them and them ramp up again, I ramped up all users and used pause time in the scenario.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Created to injection scenarios that run in parallel, one is your usual load while the other is your additional users that you would like to use as your spike:

   ```
   setUp(scenario.inject(rampConcurrentUsers(1) to (numberOfTestUsers) during (Config.rampUpDuration minutes))
     .protocols(httpconf),
     peakScenario.inject(rampConcurrentUsers(1) to (numberOfPeakTestUsers) during (Config.rampUpDuration minutes))
       .protocols(httpconf))
   ```
2. The scenario itself has a parameterised pause time at the beginning, so you can either shoot it with pause or without:

   ```
   scenario(name).feed(feed).forever() {

         doIf(isPeakDelay) {
           pause(pauseDuration + getRandomPeakDelayInSeconds)
         }
           .exec(api.call1)
           .exec(api.call2)
          ....}
   ```

   (Note the addition of random time for the pause, you dont want all users to shoot at once)

To recap, in this solution you will end up having two scenarios running in parallel - one scenario shoots users during the whole duration of the test while the second one initiates all peak users at the beginning of the test but pauses for your configured gap time between peaks.

Comment: If it works, use it.  But I would caution that the graphs in Gatling will not clearly indicate what is going on.  As you try to describe how you did what you did to management, they may not get it.

Comment: I would also run it for 24 hours straight, and make sure that the traffic doesn't smooth out over time.  If you use random pauses, it might just do that.  Slowly, perhaps, but it is important to make sure it is slowly enough to get you through your intended run duration.

Comment: Goog point! I will verify that. Thank you very much for you assistant!

Answer (score 2):

You could actually do it manually, e.g. if you wanted to surge once every 8 hours, you could do something like this, where the sum of `surgeRampTime`, `recoveryTime`, and `quiescenceTime` adds up to an hour:

```
setUp( behavior.inject(
  rampUsers( 0 ) to ( baseline ) during ( rampUpTime ),

  // first surge
  rampUsers( baseline ) to ( surge    ) during ( surgeRampTime ),
  rampUsers( surge    ) to ( baseline ) during ( recoveryTime ),
  constantConcurrentUsers  ( baseline ) during ( quiescenceTime ),

  // second surge 
  rampUsers( baseline ) to ( surge    ) during ( surgeRampTime ),
  rampUsers( surge    ) to ( baseline ) during ( recoveryTime ),
  constantConcurrentUsers  ( baseline ) during ( quiescenceTime ),

  ...

  // final surge 
  rampUsers( baseline ) to ( surge    ) during ( surgeRampTime ),
  rampUsers( surge    ) to ( baseline ) during ( recoveryTime ),
  constantConcurrentUsers  ( baseline ) during ( quiescenceTime ),

  // end of test ramp down
  rampUsers( baseline ) to ( 0 ) during ( rampDownTime )
```

Of course, you probably already thought of this, and didn't like it because it is an annoying way to program.  You want a more elegant way of accomplishing the same thing.

The secret is, the `.inject()` method takes a variable number of parameters.  Which means it can also take in a List of parameters.  So, you can write a function with returns just such a list, constructed in your favorite list construction logic.  Then, you can pass the return value from that function to the `.inject()` method, and get the same outcome.  For example:

`setUp( behavior.inject( surgeInjection( 8 ) ) )`

Now all you need to do is build the `surgeInjection` function, which might look something like this.

```
def surgeInjection( cycles : Int ) : List[InjectionProfileFactory] = {
  var list = new List[InjectionProfileFactory]()
  list += ( rampUsers( 0 ) to ( baseline ) over ( rampUpTime ) )
  var i = cycles // or use your favorite looping construct here
  while ( i > 0 ) {
    // adjust the functions to match your injection type (open or closed model)
    list += rampUsers( baseline ) to ( surge )    during ( surgeRampTime )
    list += rampUsers( surge    ) to ( baseline ) during ( recoverTime )
    list += constantConcurrentUsers  ( baseline ) during ( quiescenceTime )
    i -= 1
  }
  list += rampUsers( baseline ) to ( 0 ) during ( rampDownTime )
  return list
}
```

Now, obviously, this is more like pseudo-code than real code.  You'll want to use the right injection functions, parameterize stuff to make it reusable, defining things like the baseline injection levels, the surge levels, which kind of ramp to use to ramp the users (I suggest that the Heaviside ramp is probably the best choice for the surge ramping), and durations, etc., etc., etc.

But the principle to take away is: you can write a function to return what you would otherwise have to hand-code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realise that it is possible to inject a sequence of "behaviours" and your function solution is excellent.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested yet I still fail, you can see the updated post for more info.